# Javascript banners not working in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, adobe-edge

I've had some banners in Adobe Edge, and they're working fine in everything except Safari.

Banners can be viewed here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2tpnkVJi9v9cm5QYmNWUS1zaTQ&usp=sharing

Does anybody know the reason these aren't working?

Comment: I've gone ahead and made a few minor adjustments to the post. Avoid clutter, and things that don't pertain to the post, as they usually detract from the question at hand. Also, have a look at creating a [mcve]. Simply dumping a bunch of code in a zip file, and saying it's not working, is most likely not going to gain much traction here. Tell us exactly why it isn't working, maybe perhaps the error you're getting in the safari console. Perhaps create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), so that we can see why it's not working first hand. Help us help you!

Comment: Hi FrankerZ, thanks for the advice. I'm not a developer myself so I'm not sure how to do the things you're suggesting. The banners have been created for me and I'm struggling to get them fixed. If the html file in the zip folder is opened in Safari the errors are quite obvious with regards to the animation. I'm sorry I'm not able to offer any more information unless there's any more specific questions / comments that i may be able to answer

Comment: To give a bit more info - one banner is playing backwards, one seems to have duplicated the animation on top of itself and the third is part way through when it loads! Fine in all other browsers but they seem to have fallen apart in Safari, cheers

Comment: The zip files are not helping in this case, because we'd have to host them somewhere in order to reproduce the issue you're experiencing. Perhaps you can host them somewhere, and give us a link? You should be able to use jsfiddle to give us a working example as well. You say "the errors are quite obvious", so show them to us (Create an image, or a quick gif of the issue). Right now, I can't see anything, and in order for me to try and debug this issue, I'd have to again host them somewhere. Without you helping us, you're going to have a tough time getting assistance from others.

Comment: Ok FrankerZ, thanks for the help. I'll do that now and will update the thread shortly, much appreciated